# Update scrapy settings based on spider property

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Is there a way with scrapy to dynamically **set** the settings for a spider given at runtime? 
I want to add an `isDebug` variable to my spider and depending on it's value I want to adjust log level, pipelines and various other settings ...

When trying to manipulate the settings as said in the manual, like this:

```
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        settings['USER_AGENT'] = 'Overwridden-UA'
```

I always get `TypeError: Trying to modify an immutable Settings object`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Settings` object is immutable by itself, but has number of set methods, for ex `settings.set` [https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/settings/**init**.py#L234](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/129421c7e31b89b9b0f9c5f7d8ae59e47df36091/scrapy/settings/__init__.py#L234)

Recent versions of Scrapy (beginning from 1.0) spiders has class method `update_settings`

```
@classmethod
def update_settings(cls, settings):
    settings.setdict(cls.custom_settings or {}, priority='spider')
```

which is intended to override settings with ones presented in `custom_settings` property of the spider. So to reach your goal you can override that method in some way like that

```
class TheSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'thespider'
    is_debug = True
    custom_debug_settings = {
       # Put your debug settings here
    }

    @classmethod
    def update_settings(cls, settings):
        settings.setdict(getattr(cls, 'custom_debug_settings' \
                                      if getattr(cls, 'is_debug', False) \
                                      else 'custom_settings', None) or {},
                         priority='spider')
```

And of course there is project-wide 'two scoops of Django' way to have custom settings file for debug purposes, so it could be something like that:

**settings.py** (add to the end of the file):

```
try:
    from dev_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

then you can create **dev_settings.py** next to settings.py and add there settings you'd like to customize for your development purposes - them will be overwritten if **dev_settings.py** exists or import will be just ignored if not.

Comment: This seems to work partially. My `custom_debug_settings` are populated correctly, however, it isn't applied. I tried to set the log level to "DEBUG" and when I call `self.settings.attributes['LOG_LEVEL']` in a `parse()` function it gives the correct value, but it doesn't show debug messages. Any ideas?

Comment: Of course. If you'll have a look at Scrapy source code you'll see that it creates logger before processing spider custom_settings, so there is no way to affect default logger by modifying settings. You should either use import settings approach from the above or add custom log handler/create custom logger.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I also accepted your answer now, as my problem is a different matter. The import settings approach isn't feasible for my needs. Custom log handling seems not that easy as well, because the logs created are not actually done by the spider, but the crawler. So I will try and figure out if there is a way to create a new logger (using the spider's actual settings) in the crawler.

Comment: I needed to use different settings values in different spiders, like FEED_URI has different values per spider, so I used this method to set FEED_URI in each spider. Worked nice on Scrapy 1.5.1. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is helpful as well since this is what I needed and what actually worked for me for my use-case where I too had a few set of settings that I wanted updated in the custom spider settings on runtime
(Note: Answer inpired by [mizhgun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4591941/mizhgun), thanks to mizhgun, @stackoverflow and the whole dev community)

```
settings_to_be_updated = {
    'USER_AGENT': 'Overwridden-UA',
}

class SpiderName(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider_name'
    is_debug = True
    custom_settings = {
       # Put your all your custom settings here
    }

    @classmethod
    def update_settings(cls, settings):
        cls.custom_settings.update(settings_to_be_updated)
        settings.setdict(cls.custom_settings or {}, priority='spider')
```

Comment: " {}, priority='spider')" what does this mean? Especially the empty curly brackets? Thank you.