# Scrapy - change settings at runtime based on attribute provided

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm having fun with scrapy, working on this [project](https://github.com/rugantio/fbcrawl/blob/master/fbcrawl/spiders/fbcrawl.py), a spider for facebook's posts.

I would like to change the CONCURRENT_REQUESTS parameter in settings.py at **runtime**, if a boolean attribute is provided

I tried overwriting the **from_crawler** method as follows, but it seems not to work

```
@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler, **kwargs):
    settings = cls(crawler.settings)
    if 'conc' in kwargs:
        settings.set('CONCURRENT_REQUESTS',32)
    return settings
```

Can you please show me how to it properly, and also how to change the __init__. Should I move all that the attribute parsing in from_crawler?
Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update scrapy settings based on spider property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134570/update-scrapy-settings-based-on-spider-property)

Comment: have you tried something like `scrapy crawl spider -s CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=32`?

Answer (score 1):

`CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting used in [scrapy.core.downloader.total_concurrency](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/downloader/__init__.py#L84).
Settings itself are immutable. But `scrapy.core.downloader` object is mutable.

You can dynamically change this value from spider methods.

```
class FacebookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
.......    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'conc' in kwargs:
            self.crawler.engine.downloader.total_concurrency = 32
```

....

Answer (score 1):

Based on this informative [issue#4196](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html#telnet-console-usage-examples) combined with the [telnet console](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/telnetconsole.html) it is possible to do it, even post-execution.

Attach a telnet client to the *port* (e.g. `1234`) & *password* logged when `scrapy crawl` command is launched, and issue the following interactive Python statements to modify the currently running `downloader`:

```sh
$ telnet  127.0.0.1  6023  # Read the actual port from logs.
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Username: scrapy
Password: <copy-from-logs>
```

```py
>>> engine.downloader.total_concurrency
8
>>> engine.downloader.total_concurrency = 32
>>> est()
Execution engine status

time()-engine.start_time                        : 14226.62803554535
engine.has_capacity()                           : False
len(engine.downloader.active)                   : 28
engine.scraper.is_idle()                        : False
engine.spider.name                              : <foo>
engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider)            : False
engine.slot.closing                             : False
len(engine.slot.inprogress)                     : 32
len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or [])            : 531
len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs)                  : 0
len(engine.scraper.slot.queue)                  : 0
len(engine.scraper.slot.active)                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.active_size                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size               : 0
engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout()             : False
```

The same interactive statements above can be written as code in `Crawler.parse()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that since I can just use the "-s CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=32" at runtime. Another option would have been to overwrite the update_settings method, here's a reference for anybody who runs into this issue: 
[Update scrapy settings based on spider property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134570/update-scrapy-settings-based-on-spider-property)